# php regex issues

Tags: php, regex

I have a pattern match here that looks like it should work fine. However any input I give makes the conditional fail. I will handle the '99999-9999' case after I get the '99999' case working.

$ZipCode is a textfield that is being submitted on POST.

```
$ZipCode                        = $_POST["ZipCode"];

if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{5}$/", $ZipCode))
{$error_str .= "The zip code you enter must be in the form of: '99999' or '99999-9999'\n";}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{?><script>var error = <?= json_encode($error_str);?>;
   alert(error);
  </script>
<?}
```

'11111'  fails and '111111' also fails

Comment: How do you know that the conditional is failing? Have you tried debugging to see what the value of `$error_str` is immediately after the conditional executes?

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work correctly. Example:

```
$ZipCode = "111111";

if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{5}$/", $ZipCode))
{
    echo "Incorrect format";
}
```

Result:

```
Incorrect format
```

Try entering some invalid input to see if the error message is displayed.

---

To handle both cases at once you can use this regular expression:

```
/^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/
```

Comment: There must be an error with the content of your `$ZipCode` variable

Comment: Colin HERBERT's approach is a good suggestion so +1 for that, but it's not the only possible error. Another is that you might be modifying the file but forgetting to save it. It happens a lot... it's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Or you might be modifying a different file from the one you are running.

Comment: Edited code again. Maybe this will provide more clarification.

Comment: Did you try to echo your variable before doing the regex check ?

Comment: When I set $ZipCode = 11111 and echo $ZipCode, it prints 455. This must be the problem.

Comment: The issue was in the html. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry about question but what means ?: in parentheses?

Comment: @Centurion: It makes the parentheses non-capturing. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html for more information.